# Aharanov cashier effect

Tags: quantum-mechanics

How to show that lagrangian remain same when charge interacts with line of magnetic moments or magnetic moment interact with the line of charge in the aharnov cashier experiment

Comment: It might be a good idea to start by writing down the Lagrangian for a particle with charge or/and with electric/magnetic dipole, that is immersed in electromagnetic field. Do you know how to do that? Also, which papers/books have you read on Aharonov-Casher and He-MacKellar-Wilkens effects?

Comment: Aharonov bohm griffth, and the 1984 paper for cashier